# Convert Character to Factor R

Tags: r, character

I have the following data:

```
> str(hiv_data)
'data.frame':   500 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ HIV.status     : chr  "HIV negative" "HIV negative" "HIV negative" "HIV negative" ...
 $ edu.years      : int  8 7 5 8 1 6 7 NA 4 5 ...
 $ wealth.quintile: int  5 4 5 5 2 4 2 NA 4 NA ...
 $ res.type       : chr  "Urban" "Urban" "Urban" "Urban" ...
 $ marital.status : chr  "Married" "Never married before" "Never married before" "Never married before" ...
 $ province       : chr  "WCP" "FSP" "FSP" "WCP" ...
 $ employment     : chr  "yes" "no" "no" "no" ...
 $ age            : int  27 32 26 18 44 24 18 NA 24 NA ...
>
```

I am performing forward selection to find a model with response HIV.status. I need to change the response to a factor with labels "Negative" and "Positive" coded as 0 and 1. I have tried doing the following:

```
hiv_data$HIV.status<-factor(hiv_data$HIV.status,levels=c(0,1),labels=c("HIV negative","HIV positive"))
```

But that results in the entire column consisting of NA values. Any help?

Comment: You are confusing levels and labels. They should be specified the other way around. However, for modelling there is no reason to have 0/1 as labels. you could just use `factor(hiv_data$HIV.status)`.

Comment: If I use just factor(...) it converts it to the follows: ```HIV.status     : Factor w/ 2 levels "HIV negative",..: 1 NA 1 1 2 1 1 1 NA 1 ...``` For modelling is it fine if they are coded as 1 and 2?

Comment: If the modelling functions works with factors as a response, there shouldn't be any issues. If it doesn't, you should convert the factor into an integer (and subtract 1).

Answer (score 0):

```r
hiv_status <- sample(c('HIV negative', 'HIV positive'), size = 10, replace = TRUE)
hiv_status
#>  [1] "HIV positive" "HIV negative" "HIV positive" "HIV negative" "HIV negative"
#>  [6] "HIV negative" "HIV negative" "HIV negative" "HIV negative" "HIV positive"

factor(hiv_status, labels = c('HIV positive', 'HIV negative'))
#>  [1] HIV negative HIV positive HIV negative HIV positive HIV positive
#>  [6] HIV positive HIV positive HIV positive HIV positive HIV negative
#> Levels: HIV positive HIV negative

hiv_status <- +(hiv_status == 'HIV positive')
hiv_status
#>  [1] 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. This converts it to an integer though, I need it to a factor.

Comment: What about changing the last line to as.factor(hiv_status == 'HIV positive')